# Extended displays with wrong proportions

Tags: scaling, extended-desktop

**Q**: I have two monitors with different scaling on the same window. Any ideas on how to fix this issue? I also have a minor issue with new windows or browser windows opening half off screen and I think it could be related by not sure.

**Info**: I have a Optiplex 990 with an NVidia GTX 750 Ti for CAD and modeling on Windows 10. I'm running two monitors, the first being a DellP2213 over DVI and the second being a Dell UP3214Q over Mini DP. Both monitors are set to native and I haven't made any changes to scaling or resolutions.

I've included [four pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HOio.jpg) so you can see what I'm talking about, as well as two shots from the display settings.

The first image is a photo of the layout.
[image: Photo of setup]

Next is the print screen of the layouts.
[image: print screen rendering]

The other two pictures show the basic settings of the monitors.
[image: monitor one settings]
[image: monitor two settings]

If anyone needs more information, please let me know.

**Edit**: Tried updating drivers and removing the NVidia Control Panel settings. No dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works as expected.

Your screens have different physical pixel sizes.

- Dell UP3214Q's pixels are 0.182 mm in size with density of 140 PPI (pixels per inch)
- Dell P2213's pixels are 0.282 mm in size with density of 90 PPI

Task Manager window on your screenshot is 806px high. Divide that by screen's density and you get respectively 5.76" (146 mm) and 8.96" (227 mm).

From what I see on your screenshot, scaling works properly: larger screen has higher density, so Windows upscales everything to make it reasonably readable and crisp. Stuff on smaller screen uses default scaling of 100%.

When a window is split between two screens, Windows has to choose whether it will scale it or not. It can't do both - window needs to have fixed dimensions. It can't be 806px high on right half and, say, 537px on left half. Once the window is entirely on smaller screen, Windows will stop scaling it.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling is working. You have the resolution on one monitor set a lot higher then the other so you are getting the scaling difference when Task Manager overlaps both monitors. Make the resolution the same on both monitors.

I would also use the correct Nvidia drivers and the Nvidia Control Panel. It is much better than Windows.